# Make Dynamic Forms

Tags: forms, dynamic, guptateamdeveloper, centura

I'm using Centura / TeamDeveloper 6.1

Is it possible to make the content of a Dialog / Window dynamic?

For example if I load a table inside a tab it is dynamic because the child table always takes the size of the tab.
I want the same behaviour with buttons etc. not that they always change size but that they move their position to stay like in the center no matter how far I resize the window without me having to write a function that calculates everything and that moves them around.
In C++ / QT I would use Layouts.

As it is right now I maximize the Window but the design is stuck on the left side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Team Developer does not offers support this feature in native way.

however you can design your app to capturing when the formwindow size change and so your visual objects can change their position according the new container size.

there are some samples demonstrating this behaviour.

please, do a search [here](http://tdsamples.daverabelink.net/) for "resize" samples